# Is it possible to declare a Fortran dynamic array with lower and upper bounds

Tags: arrays, fortran, dynamic-arrays

For static array one can explicitly define the lower bound like this:

```
real, dimension(2:6) :: numbers
```

I understand that dynamic arrays are declared like this:

```
real, dimension(:), allocatable :: numbers
allocate(numbers(6))
```

Is it possible to declare a dynamic array with a lower bound and/or an upper bound? If yes, how? If no, is there a reason why was this not or can't be implemented?

Comment: yes, you can : `allocate(numbers(2:6))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, very simply:

```
allocate(numbers(2:6))
```

The upper bound must always be specified, but the lower bound is optional (and taken to be `1` if omitted).